# Solution to $(x+1)^M-2=0\mod(x^a-1,M)$ with $a|M$.

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

My exercise sheet requires me to look at the following. I am looking for an elementary solution to (all polynomials have integer coefficients):

Do there exist cases of *a>1* and *M* integers with *a* dividing *M* such that $(x+1)^M-2=0\mod(x^a-1,M)$?

So far I can prove no such cases exist for $a=2,3,4$ but can't make any further progress. Any help would much be appreciated!

Comment: You may use $x^M \equiv 1 \bmod (x^a-1)$ for simplification.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it.